# Excel VBA - How To Deselect A Previosuly Selected Item In A Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, deselect

I have a userform (uf1_assess_sched) in my Excel VBA project that has a listbox (uf1_listbox3).

When the user selects a single item in this listbox, a second userform (group_1) is opened allowing the user to enter information specific to the selection she made on the first userform. Should the user wish to abandon further entry on group_1, she can exit by clicking a commandbutton called Exit.

Upon exiting, group_1 is unloaded, and uf1_assess_sched takes the forefront. The idea is to allow the user to select another item from uf1)listbox3. However, the selection she originally made is still selected.

How do I deselect this previously made selection.

I have tried:

```
With uf1_assess_sched
    .uf1_listbox3.listindex = -1
End With
```

This is the most relevant I could find in any of my searches.

Following Patrick's suggestion, with my limited understanding of Excel VBA, this is how I interpreted his instructions.

```
With uf1_assess_sched
    For i = 0 To .uf1_listbox3.ListCount - 1
        If .uf1_listbox3.Selected(i) = True Then
            .uf1_listbox3.Selected(i) = False
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

This to regrettably didn't work. The code did find the true selection, but the entry remained selected in the listbox and also triggered the uf1_listbox3_Click event.

I hope I am providing feedback in the appropriate way, by simply editing my original post. I'm not sure how to add code to a comment. StackOverflow is a new format for me, so doing my best.

With the latest code so kindly provided by Patrick, I managed to get so far before I encountered an error. I made some adaptations to reflect userform and listbox names. I'm getting a "Method or data member not found. " error with the code in the second userform, group_1.

```
Private Sub exit1_Click()

Dim ui2 As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

If ws_vh.Range("E2") > 0 Then 'unsaved info
    Me.Label34.Caption = "    Saving unsaved rental data."
    Me.Label34.BorderColor = RGB(50, 205, 50)
    lastrow = ws_rd.Cells(ws_rd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws_rd.Range("A3:FZ" & lastrow).Sort key1:=ws_rd.Range("A3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Debug.Print Me.Name, "exit1_Click() called"
    uf1_assess_sched.ListBox3_DeSelect    '<--- Error with ".Listbox3_DeSelect"
    Unload Me

    'Unload group_1
    'End
    Exit Sub
End If

If ws_vh.Range("B2") > 0 Then   'Outstanding rentals?
    ui2 = MsgBox("You still have " & ws_vh.Range("C2") & " rentals with critical missing rental information." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
        & "Active (Sports) rentals: " & ws_vh.Range("B3") & Chr(13) & "Passive (Picnics) rentals: " & ws_vh.Range("B4") & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
        & "Are you sure you wish to exit?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "OUTSTANDING RENTAL INFORMATION")
    If ui2 = vbYes Then
        If ws_vh.Range("N4") > 0 Then
            Me.Label34.Caption = "    Saving unsaved rental data."
            Me.Label34.BorderColor = RGB(50, 205, 50)
            lastrow = ws_rd.Cells(ws_rd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ws_rd.Range("A3:FZ" & lastrow).Sort key1:=ws_rd.Range("A3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Workbooks("Sports15c.xlsm").Activate
            mbEvents = False

            Debug.Print Me.Name, "exit1_Click() called"
            uf1_assess_sched.ListBox3_DeSelect    '<--- Error with ".Listbox3_DeSelect"
            Unload Me
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Unload Me
            End
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
 End If

Unload group_1
End
End Sub
```

I did put the subs ListBox1_DeSelect() and ListBoxDeSelect(oListBox As Object) in a separate module (perhaps that is the problem).

Here is that code ...

```
Sub ListBox3_DeSelect()
ListBoxDeSelect Me.uf1_listbox3
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxDeSelect(oListBox As Object)
Dim i As Long
If TypeName(oListBox) <> "ListBox" Then Exit Sub
bSkipEvent = True
With oListBox
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            .Selected(i) = False
        End If
    Next
End With
bSkipEvent = False
End Sub
```

---

Here is my most recent code (July 19th) ...

USERFORM 1 - uf1_assess_sched (holds listbox for which which user makes selection)

```
Private Sub uf1_listbox3_Click()
    If mbEvents Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Me.Name, "uf1_listBox3_Click() called"
    If bSkipEvent Then Exit Sub
    With uf1_listbox3
        Debug.Print Me.Name, "uf1_listBox3_Click() ListIndex: " & .ListIndex & " (" & .List(.ListIndex) & ")"
        group_1.Show
        'UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = .List(.ListIndex) ' This won't have effect if UserForm2 is True on ShowModal
    End With
End Sub
```

USERFORM 2 - group_1 (allows user to enter additional data based on the value selected in userform1. User my opt to abandon by pressing EXIT button (exit1))

```
Private Sub exit1_Click()

    Dim ui2 As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    If ws_vh.Range("E2") > 0 Then 'unsaved info
        Me.Label34.Caption = "    Saving unsaved rental data."
        Me.Label34.BorderColor = RGB(50, 205, 50)
        lastrow = ws_rd.Cells(ws_rd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ws_rd.Range("A3:FZ" & lastrow).Sort key1:=ws_rd.Range("A3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Unload group_1
        'End
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws_vh.Range("B2") > 0 Then   'Outstanding rentals?
        ui2 = MsgBox("You still have " & ws_vh.Range("C2") & " rentals with critical missing rental information." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
            & "Active (Sports) rentals: " & ws_vh.Range("B3") & Chr(13) & "Passive (Picnics) rentals: " & ws_vh.Range("B4") & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
            & "Are you sure you wish to exit?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "OUTSTANDING RENTAL INFORMATION")
        If ui2 = vbYes Then
            If ws_vh.Range("N4") > 0 Then
                Me.Label34.Caption = "    Saving unsaved rental data."
                Me.Label34.BorderColor = RGB(50, 205, 50)
                lastrow = ws_rd.Cells(ws_rd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                ws_rd.Range("A3:FZ" & lastrow).Sort key1:=ws_rd.Range("A3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Save
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Workbooks("Sports15c.xlsm").Activate

                Debug.Print Me.Name, "EXIT1_Click() called"
                    'UserForm1.ListBox1_DeSelect ' No longer used.
                Set oListBoxToDeselect = uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3 ' [M2] This is required for the DelayedListBoxDeSelect(), if top right [X] is clicked, it won't do DeSelect
                Unload Me
            Else
                Unload Me
                End
            End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
     End If
            'If ws_vh.Range("N4") > 0 Then
            '    MsgBox "Unsaved rental data. Saving."
            '    lastrow = ws_rd.Cells(ws_rd.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            '    ws_rd.Range("A3:FZ" & lastrow).Sort key1:=ws_rd.Range("A3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
            '    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            '    ThisWorkbook.Save
            '    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            '    Unload Me
            'Else
            '    Worksheets("DYNAMIC").Activate
            '    Unload Me
            'End If
        'End If
    Unload group_1
    'Worksheets("DYNAMIC").Activate
    End

End Sub
```

For the purpose of testing assume ws_vh.Range("B2") > 0

And the independent helper module ...

```
Option Explicit

' Generic ListBox Deselector
Sub ListBoxDeSelect(oListBox As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    If TypeName(oListBox) <> "ListBox" Then Exit Sub
    bSkipEvent = True
    With oListBox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                .Selected(i) = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
    bSkipEvent = False
End Sub

' METHOD 2 [M2] - When UserForm's ShowModal = True
Sub DelayedListBoxDeSelect()
    Dim i As Long
    If TypeName(oListBoxToDeselect) <> "ListBox" Then Exit Sub
    bSkipEvent = True
    With oListBoxToDeselect
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                .Selected(i) = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
    bSkipEvent = False
    Set oListBoxToDeselect = Nothing
End Sub
```

group_1 userform terminate code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Debug.Print Me.Name, "UserForm_Terminate() called"
    Set oListBoxToDeselect = uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3 ' [M2] This is required for the DelayedListBoxDeSelect(), if top right [X] is clicked, it won't do DeSelect
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "DelayedListBoxDeSelect" ' [M2] Sechedules the Sub named "DelayedListBoxDeSelect" to execute in 1 second.
End Sub
```

PART 2 - An alternate scenario requiring selection to be deselected.

```
If i = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to eliminate."
    '--- > Deselect the user selection in uf_assess_sched.uf1_listbox2 < ---
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried go thru `uf1_listbox3.Selected(i)` from 0 to `.ListCount-1`, if it's True set it to False.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your reply. Very much appreciated. See my changes in my OP. I may have misinterpreted your suggestion as I was unable to make it work.

Comment: You got the idea and execute it correctly. But without your workflow of the userforms, I can only suggest adding a Global Boolean variable to *skip control events*, say `bSkipEvents` (initialize to False, the cmdbutton in group_1 sets it True), then in the controls events code, add `If bSkipEvents Then : bSkipEvents = True : Exit Sub : End If`. This should allow you skip once.

Comment: Thank you again Patrick. I appreciate the extra effort in creating a solution. I think I see where you are going with your latest suggestion. However, I am getting an error. Please see the edit of my OP.

I did take the liberty of adjusting userform and listbox names to reflect my needs. I also took out the reference in the userform1.listbox1 click code for textbox1.  I

Comment: Sorry to confuse you with the idea of taking `ListBoxDeSelect()` out to normal module. I have edited my solution to fit. You can also skip `Sub ListBox3_DeSelect()` and just use `ListBoxDeSelect uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3` in place of the error line.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I have changed my code and am pleased to say I am no longer receiving any errors. But I am not getting the results I was hoping for. The code is effective in identifying the selected value `.selected(i)`, and does reset it to false `.Selected(i) = False`. However, the selected item in the listbox remains highlighted rather than the dotted selection you have illustrated in Image #2. So, it does accomplish the functional concern, but the aesthetics remain a concern.

Comment: I can only replicate when the 2nd userform is closed (without calling `ListBoxDeSelect`). If you want to DeSelect it automatically when 2nd UserForm is closed, place the deselect call in `UserForm_Terminate()` within *UserForm2*. The 2nd UserForm's **ShowModal = False**?

Comment: Sorry to be a bother Patrick, but I'm still not having any luck.

Both forms showmodal properties are set to true.
I added a userform_terminate procedure in the 2nd userform (group_1) with `ListBoxDeSelect uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3`
The selection in uf1_listbox3 still shows selected. I must have somethingin my code interfering that is out of the ordinary that you can't see.

Comment: When a UserForm `ShowModal` is set to True, you need to use a different approach as direct changes are not allowed. Will update codes very soon.

Comment: Wow Patrick ... credit to you for hanging on through this! With both form's properties showmodule = true, and with your last code changes, I ran through an example. The only observations I can report on is that both forms closed. And that was that.

Comment: My OP has my current code posted.

Comment: Did you forgot the first 2 lines in [UserFormsHelper] where the 2 critical public variables are declared? If regardless of what user do on *group_1* will deselect *uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3*, put `Set oListBoxToDeselect = uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3` then `Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "DelayedListBoxDeSelect"` in group_1's `UserForm_Terminate()`. All ingredients are provided, just need to put them in right places.

Comment: I originally had those thwo variables declared in a unique module that holds most of the public variables I use in my application. This module also sets many of these public varibale fro use throughout my application. I will execute this module to load all the public variables before opening uf1_assess_sched. Even after moving these two declarations to the helper module, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you meant with the rest of your message Patrick. Sorry. From my interpretation, I moved `Set oListBoxToDeselect = uf1_assess_sched.uf1_listbox3` from its original spot in my exit click code to my userform terminate code. See this procedure in my OP code. With this change, the result is both userforms closing. :-(

Comment: It sounds like something else is causing the first UF to close. Put a break point in `Sub DelayedListBoxDeSelect` and step if something went wrong. Are there any `On Error Resume Next` through out your application?

Comment: No "On Error Resume Next" code except in a function, but it is closed up with a "On Error GoTo 0" . I broke the code at the point you suggested Patrick, but both userforms closed before encountering that break. `TypeName(oListBoxToDeselect)` must have equaled "listbox" as the sub was exited.

Comment: Hey Patrick!! I got it to work! Yay for your help!! I don't know what I did (beside basically start over), but it is working flawlessly! Now, I wonder if I can use this similar approach to deselect, as in my OP, but based on the value of a variable. See my PART 2 code above ...

Comment: Glad you got it to work. It's both fun and pain when dealing with events in UserForms. On your free time you should create an element of each, place a debug line on each event of it to see what are actually called when you manually action/automate things. That helps in future designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least one way to deal with unintentional UserForm Controls Events.

As I don't know how your UserForms interact with each other, the simplest I believe is to add a **Global Boolean variable** to allow you *skip* the event when required, demonstrated below.

**Edited Tip:** I have taken out the Global Boolean variable `bSkipEvent` and `Sub ListBoxDeSelect()` out to a Normal Module as a code reduction, and Calls to throw in things like `UserForm1.ListBox1`. (Ensure the ListBox in that UserForm is Shown and Enabled, otherwise add in Error trapping code).

When UserForms **`ShowModal = True`** (TSM), a different approach is required - Onw way is to schedule a Sub to be called to alter another TSM. Here I used `Application.OnTime` to schedule **DelayedListBoxDeSelect** with 1 second right before UserForm2 is completely closed. Note the extra Public object in *UserFormHelper*. Hope you understand what I am doing here.

Consider these 2 simple UserForms:
[image: UserForm1_Design]   [image: UserForm2_Design]

1. After loading UserForm1 and Clicked one of the ListBox options:
   [image: UserForm1_ListBox_Click]
2. Clicking on the Command Button on UserForm2 brings back focus to UserForm1:
   *Note how the dotted selection in the ListBox1, I think it's good to leave it like that as a reminder of what was selected previously.*
   [image: UserForm2_Cmd_Clicked]

**Codes:**
<kbd>UserForm1</kbd>

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    bSkipEvent = False
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Debug.Print Me.Name, "ListBox1_Click() called"
    If bSkipEvent Then Exit Sub
    With ListBox1
        Debug.Print Me.Name, "ListBox1_Click() ListIndex: " & .ListIndex & " (" & .List(.ListIndex) & ")"
        UserForm2.Show
        UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = .List(.ListIndex) ' This won't have effect if UserForm2 is True on ShowModal
    End With
End Sub

'Sub ListBox1_DeSelect() ' No longer used
'    ListBoxDeSelect Me.ListBox1
'End Sub
```

---

<kbd>UserFormsHelper</kbd> (Normal Module)

```
Public bSkipEvent As Boolean ' This makes accessible to Userforms and other Modules
Public oListBoxToDeselect As Object '[M2] This is for delayed ListBox Deselect method

' Generic ListBox Deselector
Sub ListBoxDeSelect(oListBox As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    If TypeName(oListBox) <> "ListBox" Then Exit Sub
    bSkipEvent = True
    With oListBox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                .Selected(i) = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
    bSkipEvent = False
End Sub

' METHOD 2 [M2] - When UserForm's ShowModal = True
Sub DelayedListBoxDeSelect()
    Dim i As Long
    If TypeName(oListBoxToDeselect) <> "ListBox" Then Exit Sub
    bSkipEvent = True
    With oListBoxToDeselect
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                .Selected(i) = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
    bSkipEvent = False
    Set oListBoxToDeselect = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

<kbd>UserForm2</kbd>

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print Me.Name, "CommandButton1_Click() called"
    'UserForm1.ListBox1_DeSelect ' No longer used.
    Set oListBoxToDeselect = UserForm1.ListBox1 ' [M2] This is required for the DelayedListBoxDeSelect(), if top right [X] is clicked, it won't do DeSelect
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Debug.Print Me.Name, "UserForm_Terminate() called"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "DelayedListBoxDeSelect" ' [M2] Sechedules the Sub named "DelayedListBoxDeSelect" to execute in 1 second.
End Sub
```

---

<kbd>Debug Output</kbd>
[image: DebugOutput]

Comment: Are you still here Patrick? LOL
I'm still having problems getting this to work. I've changed my project slightly, and I've run into the same scenario, but my adaptation seems to not work.

Comment: Interesting, but to help you need to reveal lots of codes when includes the events of controls. And if the userform(s) are ShowModal = False?